# Who can edit an existing smart contract?

Tags: security

Is there any mechanism that limits the possibility of deploying a new version of existing smart contract so that only its author can do it? Or a mechanism which indicates that smart contract A is a new version of a smart contract B?
If so, I would be grateful for indicating the name of such a mechanism in Ethereum :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contracts are always immutable - nobody can change an existing contract. You can just deploy a new version to a new address.

There are patterns to go around this "problem". You can use a proxy contract which relays calls to an actual logic contract, so the proxy contract knows the address of the logic contract. When you want to change the logic contract, you deploy a new version to a new address and change the pointer in the proxy contract to point to the new contract.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It seems that I have used wrong terminology and should use "deploy new version" instead of "override". I will edit question. But still my point is about identity - how it is determined that this new version is created by me and not by somebody who pretends to be me? Should I broadcast somewhere (eg on my website) that there is a new version of my smart contract and you can find it under address 'x' if you want to use it (so that there is 'some' proof that it's really me who have created this new version)?

Comment: Two general ways: 1) Use the same deployer, so people know it comes from the same source 2) Advertise the new contract in your 'official' chat/website/whatever. But there is no explicit "this contract has been replaced by contract B" mechanism

Comment: 1) - Do you mean that people can for example check 'Contract Creator' address on Etherscan and compare it with contract creator from previous version? or there is a different 'deployer' term with its specific definition?

Comment: Yes, the contract deployer/creator.